# Pandas: count numbers based on date, user and group

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a table in below format:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Date':['20191101','20191101','20191101','20191101','20191102','20191102','20191102','20191102'
                         ,'20191103','20191103','20191103','20191103'],
                 'User':['James','Kevin','Kevin','Corrado','James','Kevin','Corrado','Corrado','James','Kevin','Corrado','Corrado'],
                 'Department':['A','B','B','C','A','B','C','C','A','B','C','C']})
df
```

And the table is in this result:

```
df1
Date        Department      User
20191101           A         James
20191101           B         Kevin
20191101           B         Kevin
20191101           C         Corrado
20191102           A         James
20191102           B         Kevin
20191102           C         Corrado
20191102           C         Corrado
20191103           A         James
20191103           B         Kevin
20191103           C         Corrado
20191103           C         Corrado
```

My desired result table using above one to count is:

```
df2
Date        Department      User       Count
20191101           A         James        1
20191101           B         Kevin        2
20191101           C         Corrado      1
20191102           A         James        1
20191102           B         Kevin        1
20191102           C         Corrado      2
20191103           A         James        1
20191103           B         Kevin        1
20191103           C         Corrado      2
```

And I would like to build this second table df2, which counts the frequency of a user in that specific department on that specific date in a data frame format which I could directly refer to and plot charts using matplotlib. This df2 should also maintain the date, department and user, and add just 1 more column as count.

Is there any way to do such operation? Highly appreciated.

Comment: Check second answer.

Comment: thanks a lot, you may delete this post if you wish! cheers